# Keeping only the red/green/blue part of the image

Tags: image, image-processing, language-agnostic

I have made a very basic algorithm which extracts only the red / green / blue pixels of the image and displays them. However, it works well on some images and produces unexpected results in some. Like when I want to keep only green , it also keeps turquoise.

Turquoise is a shade of green but it is not what I want to display. I only want things that are 'visually' green.

Here is a sample output that shows what has gone wrong:
[image]
The algorithm picked up the turquoiose color of the flower pot on which the dog sits. [The original image is here](http://www.canadapetgrooming.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Yorkie-Cute-Puppy-In-Bucket-With-Flowers-Wallpapers.jpg).

My algorithm is below (for the green one.) All the algorithms are akin to each other.

```
void keepGreen() {
  for (int i = 0;  // iterate over the pixels of the image
  i < img.pixels.length;
  i++) {
    float inputRed = red(img.pixels[i]); // extract red
    float inputGreen = green(img.pixels[i]); // extract green
    float inputBlue = blue(img.pixels[i]); // extract blue

    int pixel = -1;

    float outputRed = -1;
    float outputGreen = -1;
    float outputBlue = -1;

    if(inputRed <= inputGreen*0.9 && inputBlue <= inputGreen*0.9){ // check if the pixel is visually green
      outputRed = inputRed; // yes, let it stay
      outputGreen = inputGreen;
      outputBlue = inputBlue;
    }else{ // no, make it gray
      int mostProminent =(int) max(inputRed, inputGreen, inputBlue);
      int leastProminent =(int) min(inputRed, inputGreen, inputBlue);
      int avg = (int) ((mostProminent + leastProminent) / 2);
      outputRed = avg;
      outputGreen = avg;
      outputBlue = avg;
      pixel = color(avg, avg, avg);
    }
    img.pixels[i] = color(outputRed, outputGreen, outputBlue); // set the pixel to the new value
  }
  img.updatePixels(); // update the image
  image(img, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, calculatedWidth, calculatedHeight); // display
}
```

**How can I avoid those errors ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experiment with raising the red and blue thresholds individually, i.e `inputGreen * 0.8` instead of `inputGreen * 0.9`  Use a tool like [Instant Eyedropper](http://instant-eyedropper.com/) or [Pixel Picker](http://plastiliq.com/pixel-picker) to verify the RGB values in those colors that you don't want, and use that as feedback to set the thresholds for elimination of the colors that you don't want.

You might also want to consider the luminance level in your calculations.  The pixels being picked up on the flower pot are *darker* than the other pixels on the flower pot.

Comment: If I multiply by a higher factor, I get more shades. Higher factor works well in case of `keepBlue()` to pick up various shades. It screws up in others.

Comment: That's why I suggested that you multiply by a lower factor.

Comment: The factor works differently for different colors. The idea is to find a mechanism that will work consistently for all colors :)

Comment: There is no such mechanism; the colors that you don't want are based on your own subjective perception.  What you call turquoise on that flower pot is still a shade of green to my eyes.  That said, the pixels that you don't want are *darker* than the others.

Comment: How would you rate the usefulness of this algorithm if I was to ever use it in a software and release it online ? Is this producing a good effect ?

Comment: Get the Instant Eyedropper or Pixel Picker tool and run it along the edge of that area that you don't want.  I think you'll find a pattern that you can use.

Comment: `How would you rate the usefulness of this algorithm` -- I think it's a decent algorithm; the effect is good, except for where it's failing on the flower pot.  I think it might have to do with that shadow being cast on the upper right hand corner of the flowerpot; it's confounding your algorithm somehow.

Comment: I used PixelPicker to analyse the turquoise pot and I saw that the individual pixels are heavily green. I guess the algorithm is cool then !! :) No mistakes

Comment: One thing you can do is provide three sliders for RGBL thresholds and let the user play with those. :)

Comment: Yes, that was just in my head. This is made in `Processing` which is just a prototyping language :)

Answer (score 1):

Just because Blue is less than Green doesn't mean the pixel doesn't look green.  For example, turquoise might be red=50, blue=200, green=150.  Perhaps you need to (also) gray out pixels that have substantial green in their own right, regardless of red/blue.

Comment: Can you expand more on this ?

Comment: Grab one of the turquoise pixels and see what it is made of (RGB).  Try adding a rule to make it gray if green > THRESHOLD regardless of blue or red.